# Visual Studio 2013 crashes when typing in editor

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2013

I have installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. The thing is that over the past few days I can't use it, since when I open a project and start typing the IDE crashes. It happens in any project no matter what the language! Log is as above:

> > Exception Type       : System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException Exception Message    : Not a valid Win32 FileTime. Exception Stack Trace:    at
> >     System.DateTime.ToFileTimeUtc()    at
> >     Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.UI.ExtensionManagerWindow.ExecutedRestartVisualStudio(Object
> >     sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)    at
> >     System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding.OnExecuted(Object sender,
> >     ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)    at
> >     System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.ExecuteCommandBinding(Object
> >     sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e, CommandBinding commandBinding)
> >     at
> >     System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(CommandBindingCollection
> >     commandBindings, Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, ICommand command,
> >     Boolean execute)    at
> >     System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(Object sender,
> >     RoutedEventArgs e, ICommand command, Boolean execute)    at
> >     System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.OnExecuted(Object sender,
> >     ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)    at
> >     System.Windows.UIElement.OnExecutedThunk(Object sender,
> >     ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)    at
> >     System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
> >     genericHandler, Object target)    at
> >     System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object
> >     target)    at
> >     System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target,
> >     RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)    at
> >     System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
> >     RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
> >     System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender,
> >     RoutedEventArgs args)    at
> >     System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean
> >     trusted)    at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.ExecuteImpl(Object
> >     parameter, IInputElement target, Boolean userInitiated)    at
> >     System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.ExecuteCore(Object parameter,
> >     IInputElement target, Boolean userInitiated)    at
> >     MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(ICommandSource
> >     commandSource, Boolean userInitiated)    at
> >     System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()    at
> >     System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()    at
> >     System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs
> >     e)    at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object
> >     sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)    at
> >     System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
> >     genericHandler, Object genericTarget)    at
> >     System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object
> >     target)    at
> >     System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target,
> >     RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)    at
> >     System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
> >     RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
> >     System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender,
> >     RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)    at
> >     System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender,
> >     MouseButtonEventArgs e)    at
> >     System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate
> >     genericHandler, Object genericTarget)    at
> >     System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object
> >     target)    at
> >     System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target,
> >     RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)    at
> >     System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source,
> >     RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)    at
> >     System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender,
> >     RoutedEventArgs args)    at
> >     System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)    at
> >     System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean
> >     trusted)    at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea() 
> >     at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs
> >     input)    at
> >     System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport
> >     inputReport)    at
> >     System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd,
> >     InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x,
> >     Int32 y, Int32 wheel)    at
> >     System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr
> >     hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean&
> >     handled)    at
> >     System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd,
> >     Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
> >     MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
> >     IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
> >     MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    at
> >     System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
> >     callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
> >     MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object
> >     source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate
> >     catchHandler) Exception Data: Key: System.Object, Value: [null]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is an addon or similiar included which fails. I would reinstall VS and make sure there is no dependies left before installing it again.

Comment: Apparently it was the extension "Bing Code Search for C#" that was causing the issue. I disabled all extensions, trying to enable them one by one. It will remain disabled until a future update perhaps. :)